# Plotting an integral

Tags: plotting

> ```
> LogLogPlot[
> 1.1183*3.086*10^-12 (c^(1/2))*2.598*10^-3 Integrate[
> x^(1/2) Rationalize[
>  Exp[-10.7*c/x] Sqrt[(1 - (125/1000)^2)*(1 - (2*4.18/125)^2) - (1 - (2 x/1000))^2], 15], {x, Rationalize[5.03], 
> Rationalize[994.97]}], {c, 10^0, 10^6}, 
>  PlotRange -> {{10^0, 10^4}, {10^-18, 10^-8}}]
> ```

it is giving a blank plot. The integral result is also puzzling. Is this the right way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NIntegrate
```

instead of `Integrate` does the job:

```
LogLogPlot[1.1183*3.086*10^-12 (c^(1/2))*2.598*10^-3 NIntegrate[   x^(1/2) Exp[-10.7*
  c/x] Sqrt[(1 - (125/1000)^2)*(1 - (2*4.18/125)^2) - (1 - (2 x/
        1000))^2], {x, Rationalize[5.03], 
Rationalize[994.97]}], {c, 10^0, 10^6},  PlotRange -> {{10^0, 10^4}, {10^-18, 10^-8}}]
```

[image]

Comment: WOW.Thanks a lot

Comment: Is there any way to write a general code for such functions and by varying different parameters, i can get different desired results?